# Where to save databases in iOS apps?

Tags: ios

this may be a simple question but i wanted to know whether apple will reject my app if i save the database simply inside the app's Library folder (Not inside cache). I plan to do this because while keeping the database and other files inside caches folder the OS will delete them in case of low memory. But i want them not to be deleted at any case. For example inn the below code i have simply changed the `NSCachesDirectory` to `NSLibraryDirectory` to save the files inside the Library.

```
NSArray *path2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [path2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/savednetsheets.xml"];
```

Please give your valuable suggestions and thoughts abouts this.

Comment: No apple wouldn't mind the location.

Comment: See Apple's [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Comment: Just print your path......

Answer (score 1):

If you want your database file to persist and to be automatically backed up during the device synchronisation, you might want to save it in the document directory
`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

That is where it will be stored if you were to use the CoreData framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will reject App if you are saving files in NSLibraryDirectory, you must save files in NSCacheDirectory .

> Put data cache files in the /Library/Caches
>   directory. Examples of files you should put in this directory include
>   (but are not limited to) database cache files and downloadable
>   content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map apps. Your
>   app should be able to gracefully handle situations where cached data
>   is deleted by the system to free up disk space.

Comment: You probably do not want the system to delete your database file when it needs to free up disk space.

Comment: @sunny: i have seen some apps that save databases in NSLibraryDirectory and still got approved by apple. Can you please share where you found the point you made (Apple will reject App if you are saving files in NSLibraryDirectory, you must save files in NSCacheDirectory)

Like marcus said, i don't want my database to be deleted at any case.